# Where can I find a full WADL spec?

Tags: wadl

I've read a great [example](http://www.mnot.net/webdesc/) of a WADL file.  I've also checked out the [WADL2Java](https://wadl.dev.java.net/wadl2java.html) tool.

But I can't seem to find a full spec of the WADL format.  I have many unanswered questions, mostly dealing with how various parts of the file relate to one another and whether I can reduce duplication by using references.

**Later**

[leppie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721465/where-can-i-find-a-full-wadl-spec/721489#721489) got the official answer, but that document kind of sucks.  Anyone have a better reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And [this](https://wadl.dev.java.net/#spec) is not it?

Comment: That seems to be both incomplete and poorly written, but, alas, I think you've got it right.

Comment: And by "that," I of course meant the PDF you linked to, not your response.

Comment: :) hehe, I didnt take it that way, most specs seem half baked, the good ones do shine though  :)

Answer (score 5):

> [leppie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721465/where-can-i-find-a-full-wadl-spec/721489#721489) got the official answer, but that document kind of sucks. Anyone have a better reference?

Meanwhile an updated specification for the [Web Application Description Language (WADL)](http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/) has been provided as a *W3C Member Submission* and it's quality has noticeably increased accordingly (though still not on par with an official *W3C Recommendation* or so); see [WADL now a W3C Member Submission](http://java.net/projects/wadl/lists/dev/archive/2009-10/message/0) for the announcement by Marc Hadley, who authored both versions.

Please note that there are some [Changes since November 2006 Publication](http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/#x3-41000D.1), you'll find more information regarding these in Marc Hadleys blog post [Draft WADL Update](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2009/02/03/draft-wadl-update).

Answer (score 4):

http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/

Answer (score 1):

Hm, there is only a PDF for the spec from 2006. Hadley made a W3C submission that can be found as well on the page @leppie linked to. [Here](http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/) is a direct link. There were some changes since 2006, for instance are now more than one `<resources>` children allowed in `<application>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the XSD for reference: http://code.w3.org/unicorn/browser/WebContent/WEB-INF/resources/schemas/wadl.xsd